# How to round double data type number about 10^26 before the redix point to int type?

Tags: double, precision

if a=123456789101112131415161718.111111111111111111111111
round a to 123456789101112131415161718.

Comment: What language??

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. An IEEE754 [`double` can only store 15-17 digits of precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) (for C#-specific link, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types)). You have a number that, even as a whole number, is 27 digits long. Therefore, the value already becomes `123456789101112000000000000` when you store it in a double.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's conceptually flawed, so the problem to be solved doesn't exist.

Comment: If the data type is long double , can it be possible to round the number??

Comment: You're not looking to round it, you're looking to truncate/floor it. If you have a language that has a `long double` type, then I imagine there is probably a `floor` funciton for it somewhere in the language's mathematical library.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C language :

```
#include <math.h>
floor(a);
```

If you use C++ language :

```
#include <cmath>
std::floor(a);
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong on the basis that a `double` can't store that much precision.